# Highcharts - Drag to move on xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to represent a lot of data in one column chart.

Here is a simple example : ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqutcruw/))

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['test A1','test B1','test C1','test D1','test E1','test F1','test G1','test H1','test I1','test J1','test K1','test L1','test M1','test N1','test O1','test P1','test Q1','test R1','test S1','test T1','test U1','test V1','test W1','test X1','test Y1','test Z1','test A2','test B2','test C2','test D2','test E2','test F2','test G2','test H2','test I2','test J2','test K2','test L2','test M2','test N2','test O2','test P2','test Q2','test R2','test S2','test T2','test U2','test V2','test W2','test X2','test Y2','test Z2']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [299, 715, 1064, 1292, 1440, 1760, 1356, 1485, 2164, 1941, 956, 544, 299, 715, 1064, 1292, 1440, 1760, 1356, 1485, 2164, 1941, 956, 544, 948, 458, 299, 715, 1064, 1292, 1440, 1760, 1356, 1485, 2164, 1941, 956, 544, 299, 715, 1064, 1292, 1440, 1760, 1356, 1485, 2164, 1941, 956, 544, 948, 458]
        }]

    });
    // set default zoom (10 items) : COMMENT IT TO SEE THE FULL CHART
    $('#container').highcharts().xAxis[0].setExtremes(0,9);
});
```

If you remove the default zoom, the display is broken.

I saw Highstock's rangeSelector feature, which is nice, but my X-Axis is not time based (and I can't afford another license).

Is there a way to implement a drag to the left or right (a kind of navigation ) on my chart ?

Comment: please provide a feedback with downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable with the [`chart.panKey`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.panKey). This will let you hold down shift key and drag mouse across x axis. See your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqutcruw/1/). Basic usage:

```
...
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift'
    },
...
```

Comment: Perfect ! I just set `panning: true`(I don't let user zoomIn) so user don't needs to hold down the panKey